# How would I put a BR tag into double quotes?

Tags: java, html, tags

How would I write a regular expression that selects the lines containing the html BR tag and surround it with double quotes?

Would this be correct? "< br>"

Answer (score 0):

No, In HTML that would be incorrect, you would just type
`<br />` however in php it could be used like `echo "<br />";`